# How to rectify Parse error in Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, ether

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

contract Carshop{
    constructor()
    {address[] carAssets;
    function createChildContract(string brand , string model) public payable{
        address newCarAsset = new CarAsset(brand, model, msg.sender);
        carAssets.push(newCarAsset);
    }
    function getDevelopedChildContracts() public view returns (address[]){
        return carAssets;
    }
    }

}
contract CarAsset{
    string public brand;
    string public model;
    string public owner;
    function CarAsset(string _brand, string _model, address _owner) public{
        brand = _brand;
        model = _model;
        owner = _owner;
    }
}
```

error facedParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
--> contracts/CarDealer.sol:7:14:
|
7 | function createChildContract(string brand , string model) public payable{
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted your smart contract code, adding some notes, in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.13;
    
contract Carshop{
    // NOTE: I moved outsite the constructor definition the declaration about 'carAssets' variable and 
    //       the two functions called 'createChildContract' and 'getDevelopedChildContract'.
    address[] carAssets;
    
    constructor() {      
    }

    function createChildContract(string memory brand, string memory model) public payable{
        // NOTE: I casted with 'address' keyword the new instance about CarAsset for retrieve the its address.
        address newCarAsset = address(new CarAsset(brand, model, msg.sender));
        carAssets.push(newCarAsset);
    }

    function getDevelopedChildContracts() public view returns (address[] memory){
        return carAssets;
    }
}

contract CarAsset{
    string public brand;
    string public model;
    // NOTE: I changed from datatype string to address
    address public owner;
    
    // NOTE: I changed the constructor parameters changing the last parameter from dataype string to address
    constructor(string memory _brand, string memory _model, address _owner) {
        brand = _brand;
        model = _model;
        owner = _owner;
    }
}
```